# Radii of spheres bounded in a regular tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, 3d, volume

> Consider a regular tetrahedron of side length $1.$ Let there be four spheres packed inside this tetrahedron, each of which have the same radius. The spheres may not be inside other spheres, and they need not be mutually tangent. What is the maximum value of the radius of a sphere which is in the regular tetrahedron.

The volume of this tetrahedron would simply be $\frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}}.$ Let the radii of all four spheres be $r,$ their volume would be $\frac{16 \pi r^3}{3}.$ We would want to maximize $\frac{16\pi r^3}{3}$ such that $\frac{16\pi r^3}{3} < \frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}}.$ However, this approach seems to be unappealing. Is there a better way of doing this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you solve the problem if you only have to fit one sphere in the tetrahedron?

Comment: Hmm, to be completely honest I'm not sure how I would do that nicely either.. I think in that case the one large sphere would have to be tangent to the sides of the tetrahedron though, which we don't know if that is the case here.

Comment: It should be tangent to the faces, not sides (edges).

Comment: Right, my bad. Through some reasearch I found out that the center of a tetrahedron divides the heights into ratio $1:3,$ though I'm still not sure how to apply this here.

Comment: That would mean that the sphere radius in the problem posed by @EricTowers is $\frac14$ of the height.

Comment: Hmm, to find the height of the tetrahedron I can use Pythagorean Theorem? I know the altitude of a equilateral triangle with side length $1$ is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$ And $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{4}=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8}.$ So the height of the tetrahedron will be $\sqrt{1^2-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8}^2}=\frac{\sqrt{37}}{8}.$  So the radius would be $\frac{\sqrt{37}}{32}$ in @EricTowers problem?

Comment: By my calculation the height of the tetrahedron is $\sqrt\frac23$.

Comment: Oh...I must've made a mistake? Also, knowing that the radius being $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{12},$ will the radius of a circle in the original problem be $\frac{1}{4}$ times the radius in @EricTowers problem?

Comment: Actually nevermind, I don't think knowing the radius of when one sphere is fit in a tetrahedron...but I really feel like there is some correlation between the two

Comment: @user Sorry for posting several times in a row but could you elaborate on how you got the height of the tetrahedron to be $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}?$ I realized I did something wrong but I'm now stuck on how you found the height again..Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh wow, my apologies, the formula to finding the height of any regular tetrahedron is $h=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}a$ where $a$ is the side length. This would be the solution to @EricTowers proposed problem is that the radius is $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{12},$ but I'm still unsure about the original proposed problem by me...

Comment: After putting one big sphere in the middle, can you shove three tiny spheres into three corners?  In the original problem, does it matter what are the radii of the smaller spheres?

Comment: Hmm, in the original problem all of the spheres have to be identical, but now that I think about it I think the spheres can be in any formation and still fit in the tetrahedron.

Comment: I understand how to solve the problem now if it was just one big circle, but I'm not sure how that realtes to when there are four identical smaller circles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual in similar problems the key to the solution is a good drawing. Let the edge $AB$ and the height of the tetrahedron drawn from $D$ be parallel to the plane of the figure. Observe that the fourth vertex $C$ of the tetrahedron coincides (in projective sense) with the foot of the height.

The point $Z$ is the center of the tetrahedron. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the centers of the spheres lying on the heights drawn from $A$ and $B$, respectively. Obviously the spheres have the largest possible radius if they touch each other. From the symmetry the touch point $N$ lies (in the projective sense) on the line $DC$.

[image]
From the similar triangles $AXQ$ and $AZC$ we have:
$$
\frac{XQ}{QA}=\frac{ZC}{CA}\implies\frac{r}{\frac12-r}=\frac{\sqrt\frac1{24}}
{\frac12}\implies r=\frac1{2+\sqrt{24}}.
$$